# Char to Int Conversion Java

Tags: java, char, int, type-conversion, precision

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    char x = 'x';
    char w = x-1;
    System.out.println(w);
}
```

Whenever I try to run the following code, I got a loss of precision. The compiler tells me that the line `char w = x-1` doesn't seem to work. How can I make the char value equal `w`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to re-cast to char as you converted to `int`

```
char x = 'x';
char w = (char)(x - 1);
System.out.println(w);
```

That will output `w`.

Comment: Why doesn't this happen automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Because `1` is an `int`. You need a cast. Like,

```
char w = (char) (x - 1);
```